# Dynamically show PDF in <div> using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I am having trouble dynamically displaying a PDF using this form/js combination.  I am having a user go into their file system, find a PDF, and show the document on the screen.  I may need to use AJAX and eventually send the pdf from the jsp/html to the servlet and grab the response to display on the screen, but I don't want to do that.  What is throwing me for a loop is that in the PDFObject parameters, when I am inputting the direct URL to the pdf "/Indexer/pdf/TEST.pdf" it works like a charm.  However, when the user goes into their filesystem and chooses their own document to view, it does not do anything at all.  Here is the code:

```
<div id="uploadPDFForm">
    <h3>Get PDF</h3>
        <form id="pdfUpload" action="IndexServlet" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="document" value="" id="pdfLocation"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="View Document" id="pdfBtn">
            <input type="button" value="pressMe" id="pdfBtn2">
        </form>
</div>

<p id="statement">Statement that is replaced with PDFembed message using <em>button click</em> </p>     

<div id="pdf">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/Indexer/_js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Indexer/_js/pdfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var str = $("#pdfLocation").val();
    var res = str.replace(/\\/g, "/");

var pObj = new PDFObject({ 

    url: res,
    //url: $("#pdfLocation"),  
    //url: "/Indexer/pdf/TEST.pdf",
    id: "myPDF",

    pdfOpenParams: {

        navpanes: 0,
        toolbar: 0,
        statusbar: 0,
        view: "FitV"

    }

});


function embed(){

    var s = document.getElementById("statement");
    var msg;

    document.getElementById("pdf").className = "embedded";  

    var htmlObj = pObj.embed("pdf");    

    if(htmlObj){
        msg = "The PDF was successfully embedded";
        s.className = "success";
    } else {
        msg = "Embed has failed.";
        s.className = "fail";
    }

    s.innerHTML = msg;

}


$("#pdfBtn2").click(function (){

    var s = document.getElementById("statement");
    var msg;

    if(pObj){

        var plugintype = pObj.get("pluginTypeFound");
        msg = "Type of PDF plugin found: " +plugintype;

        if(plugintype){
            msg += "<br/><a href='#' onclick='embed(); return false;'>Embed PDF</a>";
        } else {
            msg += "<br/>Looks like we won't be able to embed your PDF!  Doh!";
            s.className = "fail";
        }

    }

    s.innerHTML = msg;


    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to upload the PDF to the server first, you won't be able to access the actual file using `.val()`.

Comment: Yeah I hear ya, I'm trying to grab the actual string value that is populated into the "input" text box, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm going about it correctly

Comment: The browser will not allow your script to access local files. The PDF must come from the server.

Comment: Okay so I should send the file to the servlet, and embed the response in the <div>? This can be done via AJAX correct?